# Django Rest Framework APIView Parameters

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Is it possible and how to implement the APIView class that the builtin Web browseable API page will gives a form with the parameters fields specified?

Normally you get that when you using ViewSet attach to a model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use GenericAPIView the browsable API will generate a form corresponding to the `serializer_class` used.